# uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

I want to use jsonp.

I have encountered this error when writing code like this:

`uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token`

What is the problem?

```
function getAirLine(from , to , date) {

    var href = "https://api.flightstats.com/flex/schedules/rest/v1/json/from/"+from+"/to/"+to+"/departing/"+date+"?appId=[myKey1]&appKey=[myKey2]&extendedOptions=languageCode:ko";
    $.ajax({
            url : href,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success : function(datas) {
                console.log(datas);
                var dataSet = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < datas.scheduledFlights.length; i++) {
                    for(var j = 0 ; j < datas.appendix.airlines.length ; j++){
                        if(datas.scheduledFlights[i].carrierFsCode == datas.appendix.airlines[j].fs){
                            airlines = datas.appendix.airlines[j].name;
                        }
                    } 
                    var dataArr = [];
                    dataArr.push(datas.scheduledFlights[i].departureAirportFsCode);
                    dataArr.push(datas.scheduledFlights[i].departureTime.substring(11,16))
                    dataArr.push(datas.scheduledFlights[i].arrivalAirportFsCode)
                    dataArr.push(datas.scheduledFlights[i].arrivalTime.substring(11,16))
                    dataArr.push(datas.scheduledFlights[i].carrierFsCode + datas.scheduledFlights[i].flightNumber)
                    dataArr.push(airlines);
                    dataSet.push(dataArr);
                }
                console.log(dataSet);
                $('#realTime').DataTable({
                    destroy: true,
                    data: dataSet,
                    columns: [
                        { title: "From" },
                        { title: "Depart.Time" },
                        { title: "To" },
                        { title: "Arrial.Time" },
                        { title: "AirLine" },
                        { title: "AirCode" }
                    ]
                });                 
            },
            error: function(datas) {
                  console.log('실패 - ', datas);
                }
        });
}
```

Comment: exactly which line of code causes that error (your browser should be telling you) - there's no syntax error in the code you posted

Comment: An error occurs when adding url and datatype.

Comment: which line of the code you posted throws that error ...

Comment: I get an error when I add dataType: 'jsonp', 
Is there a problem with the syntax?

Comment: oh ... so `https://api.flightstats.com/flex/schedules/rest/v1/json/from/"+from+"/to/"+to+"/departing/"+date+"?appId=[myKey1]&appKey=[myKey2]&extendedOptions=languageCode:ko` is `JSONP` - perhaps that site does not actually send JSONP

Comment: judging from the documentation `api.flightstats.com` returns JSON, not JSONP ... the syntax error results in the fact that JSONP is not JSON - in other words, set `dataType: 'json'` when receiving JSON

Comment: How can I change this json type to jsonp?

Comment: why would you want to? browsers can deal with JSON quite easily. Besides if the API uses JSON, it uses JSON .. you can't change what some other site sends you (I'm beginning to suspect what the actual problem is though)

Comment: so, what's the problem when you change to `dataType: 'json',`

Comment: Using json causes an error. "Cross-Origin Read Blocking" What should I do?

Comment: ahh, there it is ... CORS ... you need to make your requests from a server, rather than a client, because that API doesn't seem to allow cross origin requests ... there's plenty of questions on SO about cross origin resource sharing (CORS) that will help